# EmberJS: Auto-Generate Record when no record ID in route

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I am creating an application which lets applicants apply through a form.  The form must auto-generate a new application if no previous application was passed in.

My `router.js` file:

```
Router.map(function () {
    this.route("apply", {path: ":application_id"}, function () {
        /* ... */
    });
});
```

And my `routes/apply.js`

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        if (params["application_id"]) {
            console.dir(params.application_id);
            return this.store.find("application", params.application_id);
        }
        else {
            console.dir(params);
            let emptyApplicant = this.store.createRecord("applicant", {isPrimary: true}), emptyApplication = this.store.createRecord("application");
            emptyApplication.set("applicant", emptyApplicant);
            return emptyApplication;
        }
    }
});
```

But navigating to `/apply` gives me the following error:

`Error while processing route: apply.index Couldn't find record of type 'application' for the id 'apply'. Error: Couldn't find record of type 'application' for the id 'apply'.
    at DS.LSAdapter.DS.Adapter.extend.find`

I checked what the `params` is, and it is `apply` in this case (I was expecting it to be `null`, and the url `apply/7g2c7` to be `7g2c7`).

How can I detect when an application ID is being sent in, and auto-generate a new application otherwise?

Comment: Shouldn't the path be

    { path: '/apply/:application_id' }

Comment: @user2105103, I tried that.  I still get the same error.

Comment: Try setting the route path to include the word "*apply*" 
`this.route("apply", {path: "/apply/:application_id"}`